# Changing the background color of the matched brace in PhpStorm 10

Tags: phpstorm

I just changed my version of PhpStorm (10) and I'd like to know how to change the background color of the matched brace.

A screenshot will be easier to explain. :)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's hard to say by looking your **custom** color schema -- it would be better if you post the same screenshot using standard Default or Darcula schemas -- at least we both will be looking at the same colors. But right now it could be `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Code | Matched brace`

Comment: **Perfect!** Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to say by looking your **custom** color schema -- it would be better if you post the same screenshot using standard Default or Darcula schemas -- at least we both will be looking at the same colors.

But right now most likely it would be `Matched brace` style -- you can find it at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Code`.